# Передать значение переменной с поддомена на домен localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, localstorage

друзья. Столкнулся с задачей, в которой необходимо передать значение переменной с поддомена на домен. Использую localstorage. В общем есть домен, и есть поддомен, а это значит, что у каждого свой файл скрипта, файл шаблона и т.д.

В файле скрипта поддомена я пишу следующее, т.е. заношу значение переменной в ячейку localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("city_id", city_id);
```

В файле скрипта домена я пытаюсь получить это значение вот так:

```
var result = localStorage.getItem("city_id");
console.log(result);
```

Но консоль отображает `undefined`

С localstorage уже работал, и не раз. Но мне непонятно одно, если это браузерное хранилище, то какая разница где ты пытаешься занести значение, и где пытаешься получить его (я про разные файлы скриптов).

Может я что-то упустил, или не до конца понимаю принцип работы localstorage.
Если localstorage так не работает, то подскажите пожалуйста другие методы передачи значения переменной с поддомена на домен, или на оборот, без разницы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Содержание хранилища `localStorage` и `sessionStorage` уникально для каждого домена, поддомена и порта. Это сделано для безопасности, чтобы сайты не могли красть данные, которые сохранили другие сайты.

Вам нужно сохранять данные на сервере, чтобы иметь возможность использовать их на любых поддоменах. Получить данные другого домена (поддомена) из браузера вы НЕ сможете никак

Comment: Нашел еще вот такое решение. Междоменный localstorage - https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage.

Comment: Не знаю насколько это решение безопасное и будет ли оно работать, но документация говорит, что такое невозможно: https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage